# What is the equivalent of SSLSessionID for TLS1.3 sessions

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, tls1.3

In TLSv1.2 the client was able to resume with the SSLSessionID. This ID stayed constant among multiple resumed sessions.

In my modified apache webserver, i have a logic, that checks the session-cookie against the SSLSessionID. If the SSLSessionID changed for the same cookie, i drop the request.

Now how could i achieve this in TLSv1.3. (The resumption of the session is not the problem, this works.)

The problem is, that the SSLSessionID **changes** for every request, also on **resumed** sessions.

Obviously my mechanism does no longer work so i need an identifier which stays constant among resumed sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: There is no strict equivalent, as the feature was dropped. But new session tickets were introduced for similar needs.

[RFC 8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-2.2) on TLS 1.3 says this:

> 2.2.  Resumption and Pre-Shared Key (PSK)
>
> [..]
>
> In TLS 1.2 and below, this functionality was provided by "session IDs"
> and "session tickets" [RFC5077].  Both mechanisms are obsoleted in TLS
> 1.3.

Section §4.1.2 about `ClientHello` also describes this extension:

> legacy_session_id:
>
> Versions of TLS before TLS 1.3 supported a
> "session resumption" feature which has been merged with pre-shared
> keys in this version (see Section 2.2).  A client which has a
> cached session ID set by a pre-TLS 1.3 server SHOULD set this
> field to that value.  In compatibility mode (see Appendix D.4),
> this field MUST be non-empty, so a client not offering a
> pre-TLS 1.3 session MUST generate a new 32-byte value.  This value
> need not be random but SHOULD be unpredictable to avoid
> implementations fixating on a specific value (also known as
> ossification).  Otherwise, it MUST be set as a zero-length vector
> (i.e., a zero-valued single byte length field).

The closest you can find is a new "session ticket", see §4.6.1

But if you go however to things like https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ you will see that all configurations are done with session tickets being disabled.

You can have a look at https://timtaubert.de/blog/2017/02/the-future-of-session-resumption/ for an explanation of the change between 1.2 and 1.3

Comment: exactly. the important thing here is to set OP_NO_TICKET in the ssl context, if one needs this backwards compatibility. also see this question here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11039